# Register desktop app that connects to instagram

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I want to create my private app that will use instagram API to find potential clients for my business. There are bunch of similar apps, but I don't trust their filtering and want to have better control on people I am reaching.

So I started from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started#register. There are bunch of issues I faced during registration:
1. The tutorial suggests to create "Facebook Login" product. As my app will run on desktop and probably written on Java, it is not clear how should I configure that product. There is no any UI controls when I select "Other". Also do I need this product if I am not planning to share this app, and always  use my own security tokens?
2. I must provide screencast for the review for Instagram product. Does it actually mean that I should stub the application as I don't have access to APIs yet?